# Can't find JED Submit Extension Button

Tags: joomla

I have registered in http://extensions.joomla.org/, selected category went as deep as there are no sub category but cant find any submitting, adding or uploading button. Can someone tell me please what could i have done wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JED have disabled extension submissions (as of 31st October) whilst they are migrate all existing extension over to the new component/site. This will hopefully be complete on the 7th November.

For more information, have a read of the following:

http://extensions.joomla.org/jed3-project-status

Hope this helps

Comment: thanks for your answer, one more question.
So it means that on on 7th  November new way will be available and all details we could know from link you have given ?

Comment: yes, the 7th November is the date given, so hopefully then, you will be able to submit your extension. The same process will apply, the only thing you will notice is styling changes and possibly feature changes, nothing major ;)

Comment: is there any news ? nothing have changed on that page since i have wrote this question.

Comment: I have spoken so someone and they are having some issues with the data migration. Keep checking the link I have provided in my answer as some updates are put there

Comment: Dear @Lodder is there any news from them it seems dev.extensions.joomla.org doesent work at all again? Do you know are they going to make it work until 2015 or not?

Comment: @user2982337 - Its now live but still quite buggy